# Wordpress Page/Post edit page keeps on loading

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, php-7.0

I have installed LAMP stack in Amazon EC2 cloud. 
Then I have installed WordPress-4.9.7. Its a fresh installation. Everything works fine. But when I try to edit/add any post/page, the browser keeps on loading.

### My php configuration:

- PHP 7.0.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
- memory_limit       = 512M
- max_execution_time =30
- max_file_uploads  = 20
- max_input_nesting_level   64
- max_input_time    = 60
- max_input_vars = 1000

Also I have tried clearing browser. After clearing cache also, the issue remains unresolved.

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: please try: disabling your theme for a default twentyX, disabling all your plugins.

Comment: Its a fresh install. So I have not installed any plugin / theme. Currently its using wordpress provided twenty-seventeen theme only.

Comment: And database is clean, from fresh install ? are other page working: taxonomy, settings, permalinks, menus...

Comment: @Mtxz yes they are working fine. Dtabase ios also from fresh install. Only page/post edit page is causing issue.

Comment: Nothing in the logs ?

Comment: No its not  reporting any error in apache error log.

Comment: Enable WP debug and log in wp config

Comment: @Mtxz no error log reported.

Comment: If you let the browser load, it goes until a timeout ?

Comment: No @Mtxz, it never goes timeout error. The major problem is, it is not causing jquery(document).ready event .

Comment: In the Chrome web dev tools, what is within the console log?

Comment: @David.J no error. Jquery version is 1.12.1